# Steps for using the natural method/direct method to make a course, how to use it to teach effectively

Tags: teaching-methods, linguistics

If I wanted to write a book or a course using the direct method/natural method, how to do it scientifically? Which methodology to use?

*My question focus about the use of linguistics theories to teach, and the method that we could develop from them.*

By direct method/natural method, I mean the one used in Lingua Latina per se. (Hans Henning Ørberg)

https://blog.classicsathome.com/2015/02/hans-h-rberg.html

There's also books using what is called "[direct method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_method_(education))".

For instance: [French by the direct method](https://archive.org/details/frenchbydirectm01schmgoog/page/n7)

The Wikipedia's article lists a few advantages, but I can't find an article to explain how to use it as a teacher, and the right methodology.

Comment: Are you wanting to create a course which merely instructs students on the method and leaves them to their own devices to make it work in their TL - or - are you wanting to create a course for a specific language?

Comment: A course for one (or more) specific languages.